# this function blockhash(block.number) return 0x000..... address why?

Tags: solidity

i learning solidity. i test blockhash(block.number) function in local and test net .
the code is

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: SimPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract BlockTest2{

     function test2() public view returns(bytes32 b46,uint number45){//当前blockhash 返回是0 原因未知
         number45 = block.number; // 当前区块号
         b46=blockhash(number45);   
    }
}
```

the result is

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blockhash of the current block is always `0` ([ethereum yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) page 33).

If you want a meaningful result, try `number45 = block.number-1`.

Comment: thanks bro. i got id . yellow pager write. 0 is left on the stack if the looked for block number is greater than or equal to the current block number or more than 256 blocks behind the current block.